# How to read value from plugin flexform in TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a plugin for a custom content element. The plugin contains a flexform. I'd like to use a value from the flexform in my TypoScript setup. How can I do this?

More specifically, the flexform is defined as:

```
 <T3DataStructure>
  <meta>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
  </meta>
  <sheets>
    <sDEF>
      <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
          <sheetTitle>LLL:EXT:cb_foundation/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:magellan.sheetTitle</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
          <settings.magellan.cols>
            <TCEforms>
              <label>LLL:EXT:cb_foundation/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:magellan.cols</label>
              <config>
                <type>input</type>
                <size>20</size>
                <eval>trim</eval>
              </config>
            </TCEforms>
          </settings.magellan.cols>
        </el>
      </ROOT>
    </sDEF>
  </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

My custom element is added to `tt_content` using the following TypoScript:

```
lib.cb_foundation.magellan = HMENU
lib.cb_foundation.magellan {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        sectionIndex = 1
        sectionIndex.type = header
        sectionIndex.useColPos = 0
        wrap = <div data-magellan-expedition="fixed"><dl class="sub-nav"> | </dl></div>
        NO {
            allWrap = <dd data-magellan-arrival="c{field:sectionIndex_uid}">|</dd>
            allWrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }
    special = list
    special.value.data = page:uid
}

tt_content.cbfoundation_magellan =< lib.cb_foundation.magellan
```

What I want to do is to set `tt_content.cbfoundation_magellan.1.sectionIndex.useColPos` using the value found in the flexform. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Typoscript does not parse values from a flexform, unfortunately.

You need an extbase controller or pi1 to get the values from the flexform and assign them to a separate template which renders your custom content element.

Extbase Example:

```php
class ContentElementsController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    public function YourContentElementAction() {
        // Get the data object (contains the tt_content fields)
        $data = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;

        // Append flexform values
        $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->readFlexformIntoConf($data['pi_flexform'], $data);

        // Assign to template
        $this->view->assign('data', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are right with the fact I cannot do this. But I think the reason you give is not the right reason. The main problem is I cannot get the content object is use from the HMENU object, I can only get the page object. In other words, it is not that I cannot read flexform from TypoScript, it is that I cannot get data from my content object when I am inside a HMENU object.

Comment: That might be also correct, but if you still have the tt_content object, the flexform fields are not accessable, because they are stored as a serialized array in the database and not computed to the other fields. Try it with ``RECORDS``

Comment: Yes, but from the `tt_content` I can read the `pi_flexform` field, and using a user function, I can parse that field.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40629229) there is a solution now in TYPO3 >= 8.4.

The feature is [documented](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.4/Feature-17309-AccessFlexformValueViaTS.html) in the TYPO3 Core Changelog.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, if the extension gridelements or TYPO3 6.2.26 bring the functionality, but the following works for me:

```
dataWrap = {field:flexform_YOURFIELD}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following StackOverflow answer describes, how plugin flexform settings of EXT News can be accessed from TS Setup using a small PHP USER Class:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006158/430742

It should be easy to adapt for other plugins and their flexform settings.

Answer (score 0):

here a simple example for the Ext: DCE:

```
20 = CONTENT
20 {
                    table = tt_content
                    select {
                        uidInList.data = GP:detailDceUid
                        uidInList.intval = 1
                    }
                    renderObj = COA
                    renderObj {
                        10 = TEXT
                        10 {
                            data = flexform: pi_flexform:settings.referenzTown
                        }
                    }
                    stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | in | |
                    stdWrap.insertData = 1
}
```