# Get FlexForm configuration in TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I need to get the page.headerData in typoscript from pi_flexform.How can implement my requirement?

```
page = PAGE
page {
  headerData {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value =<script>/**********************/</script>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not so sure about what you really need. I am *guessing* you want to access a FlexForm configuration inside your TypoScript?

Since the version 8.4 this is possible by using plain TypoScript

```
lib.flexformContent = CONTENT
lib.flexformContent {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = this
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            data = flexform: pi_flexform:settings.categories
        }
    }
}
```

> The key `flexform` is followed by the field which holds the flexform data and the name of the property whose content should be retrieved.

Before 8.4 you need to use a `userFunc` and retrieve the value by using PHP

```
 $flexFormService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FlexFormService::class);
 $flexFormKey = str_replace('.', '|', $keyParts[1]);
 $settings = $flexFormService->convertFlexFormContentToArray($flexFormContent);
```