# Reading data out of a flexform in typoscript

Tags: typo3, flexform

I try to read a flexform data out in typoscript. I tried it with several approaches, but none of them works correctly:

```
    ajax.30 = TEXT
    ajax.30.value =   {$plugin.parser.settings.maxNumber}
    ajax.40 < {$plugin.parser.settings.maxNumber}
    ajax.50 < {$plugin.parser.settings.maxNumber}
    ajax.60 = TEXT
    ajax.60.data = {$field:flexform_varNum}
    ajax.70 = TEXT
    ajax.70.data = flexform : pi_flexform:settings.varNum
```

Can anyone give me a hint for the right syntax?
I'm using Typo3 9.5.13.

Comment: A lot of time ago I used the cobj_xpath extension https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cobj_xpath you can find here an example https://docs.typo3.org/p/adwlm/cobj_xpath/master/en-us/Tutorials/UsingXpathToReadFlexformValues/Index.html (I don't know why it has been removed from the manual of the last version)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read out FlexForm data without an actual content element. 
The `CONTENT` or `COA` objects would provide that. See for example [Get FlexForm configuration in TypoScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625082/get-flexform-configuration-in-typoscript/40629229#40629229)

The feature was added in TYPO3 8.4 https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.4/Feature-17309-AccessFlexformValueViaTS.html